# Java multiple input, and display in order

Tags: java

I need a Java program that asks for the names of three runners and the time, in minutes, it took each of them to finish a race. Display the names of the runners in the order they finished.

```
     String name1=" ", name2= " ", name3=" ";
     String fast= " ", mid= " ", slow= " ";
     double faster=0, middle=0, slower=0;
     double time1 =0, time2=0, time3=0;

     Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);


         System.out.println("Enter the name of the runner: ");
         name1 = kb.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Enter the time of the runner "+ 
                    "took to finish the race (minutes): ");
         time1 = kb.nextDouble();

         System.out.println("Enter the name of the runner: ");
         name2 = kb.nextLine();

         System.out.println("Enter the time of the runner "+ 
                    "took to finish the race (minutes): ");
         time2 = kb.nextDouble();

         System.out.println("Enter the name of the runner: ");
         name3 = kb.nextLine();

         System.out.println("Enter the time of the runner "+ 
                    "took to finish the race (minutes): ");
         time3 = kb.nextDouble();





     if (time1 < time2 && time1< time3)
     {
         time1= faster;
         name1 = fast;
         if (time2<time3)
         {
             time2=middle;
             name2=mid;
             time3=slower;
             name3=slow;
         }
         else
         {
             time2 = slower;
             name2=slow;
             time3= middle;
             name3 = mid;
         }
     }
      if (time2 < time3 && time2< time1)
     {
         time2= faster;
         name2 = fast;
         if (time1<time3)
         {
             time1=middle;
             name1=mid;
             time3=slower;
             name3=slow;
         }
         else
         {
             time1 = slower;
             name1=slow;
             time3= middle;
             name3 = mid;
         }
     }
       if (time3 < time2 && time3< time1)
     {
         time3= faster;
         name3 = fast;
         if (time2<time1)
         {
             time2=middle;
             name2=mid;
             time1=slower;
             name1=slow;
         }
         else
         {
             time2 = slower;
             name2=slow;
             time1= middle;
             name1 = mid;
         }
     }

       System.out.printf("\n%10s",fast);
       System.out.println("\n%10s",mid);
       System.out.println("\n%10s",slow);

       System.exit(0);
```

So far this is all I have, but I know I did it wrong, can any help me?

Comment: What is your expected output and what is your actual output?

Comment: @Compass i have to output the three runner names in order who finished the race first to last.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I can see straight up is using `kb.nextDouble();`

Thats because the Scanner#nextDouble method does not read the last newline character of your input, and thus that newline is consumed in the next call to Scanner#nextLine

```
     System.out.println("Enter the name of the runner: ");
     name1 = kb.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Enter the time of the runner "+ 
                "took to finish the race (minutes): ");
     time1 = kb.nextDouble();

     System.out.println("Enter the name of the runner: ");
     name2 = kb.nextLine();

     System.out.println("Enter the time of the runner "+ 
                "took to finish the race (minutes): ");
     time2 = kb.nextDouble();

     System.out.println("Enter the name of the runner: ");
     name3 = kb.nextLine();

     System.out.println("Enter the time of the runner "+ 
                "took to finish the race (minutes): ");
     time3 = kb.nextDouble();
```

Change it to

```
     System.out.println("Enter the name of the runner: ");
     name1 = kb.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Enter the time of the runner "+ 
                "took to finish the race (minutes): ");
     time1 = Double.parseDouble(kb.nextLine());

     System.out.println("Enter the name of the runner: ");
     name2 = kb.nextLine();

     System.out.println("Enter the time of the runner "+ 
                "took to finish the race (minutes): ");
     time2 = Double.parseDouble(kb.nextLine());

     System.out.println("Enter the name of the runner: ");
     name3 = kb.nextLine();

     System.out.println("Enter the time of the runner "+ 
                "took to finish the race (minutes): ");
     time3 = Double.parseDouble(kb.nextLine());
```

After you fix this look at [jan-groth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/512155/jan-groth) proposed design solution.

Comment: is that a joke answer? This is not addressing the core of the OPs  code problem...

Comment: @jangroth before you become a joke understand that the input part doesn't work for him then ask him to move on to data structures... and other problems around design

Comment: I guess then we don't agree about what the problem with the given code is :)

Comment: I agree what you said to but by improving everything you said would not fix OP problem cause the input is wrong. :P FYI look at the last line of the answer ...

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a better data structure:

- Create an object for each runner that holds name and time
- Put all these objects into a collection, a list is probably a good start
- Print out names and times by looping over the sorted list of runners

And feel free to ask more questions on SOF.